# React useState not updating immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'am new to React and just stumbled upon a problem where useState does not update immediately. I've tried answers on stackoverflow but those did not work out because I have multiple useStates that each comprises a list of children components. So using useEffect does not do the trick for me. The problem for me is that when AIplayCards() is called, useStates aren't changed yet. So then AIplayCards() executes, the cards are all null.

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code snippet:

```
const Game = (props) => {
    const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false)
    const [playerCards, setPlayerCards] = useState([])
    const [opponentLeftCards, setOpponentLeftCards] = useState([])
    const [startingTurn,setStartingTurn] = useState(true)
    const [turn, setTurn] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        resetGame();
        //componentWillMount
        setMounted(true)
    }, []);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if(mounted){
            if (turn !== "player") AIplayCards()
        }
    }, [mounted]);
    //My effort to make it work

    const resetGame = async () => {
        let deck = Rules.newDeck()
        let playerCards = await Rules.setUserCards(deck)
        let opponentLeftCards = await Rules.setUserCards(deck)
        let firstTurn = Rules.setFirstTurn(playerCards, opponentLeftCards, opponentTopCards, opponentRightCards)
        //Works

        setPlayerCards(playerCards)
        setOpponentLeftCards(opponentLeftCards)
        setTurn(firstTurn)
        setStartingTurn(true)
        //here if I console.log the states and they arent changed yet.
    }
```

Just for reference purpose:

```
    const AIplayCards = () => {
        let currentPlayerCards = getCardsforTurn()
        //returns null because turn is still null, and it match with none of the the if statements in getCardsforTurn. 
          ......
```

When the rest of the code attempts to read the length of currentPlayerCards, an error is returned.

Comment: I rewrote Game as a class and using componentWillMount, my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

You should invoke your second function as a callback to setState, as setState happens asynchronously.
So `setState((state, props) => {...})` instead of `setState(object)`.
If you find that useState / setState are not updating immediately, the answer is simple: they're just queues. React useState and setState don't make changes directly to the state object; they create queues to optimize performance, which is why the changes don't update immediately.